# Comparing a moment.js obect to a timestamp from JSON response

Tags: javascript, typescript, timestamp, momentjs, utc

I am trying to compare a moment object (30 days ago) to a given timestamp. Both isBefore and isAfter are returning false. Im not sure where i'm going wrong?

```
var startdate = moment.utc().subtract(30,'days')

var RequestedDate = moment.utc('14/12/2021, 11:26')

var isbefore = startdate.isBefore(RequestedDate)
var isafter = startdate.isAfter(RequestedDate)

console.log(isafter)
console.log(isbefore)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requested date is not in the right format, based on the error emitted in [a fiddle of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/osa0yp7L/):

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

If you're able to use the ["Date + Format" constructor](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), then you can parse something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/osa0yp7L/1/):

```js
var RequestedDate = moment.utc('14/12/2021, 11:26', 'D/M/Y, H:m', true)
// "Tue Dec 14 2021 11:26:00 GMT+0000"
```

Note the use of strict mode, as in the docs:

> You may get unexpected results when parsing both date and time. The below example may not parse as you expect:
>
> ```
> moment('24/12/2019 09:15:00', "DD MM YYYY hh:mm:ss");
> ```